# $.ajax and ashx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I am using the following code to store values in aspx session.

Code:

```
 $("div.menu_body a").click(function() {               
     var linkHeaderID = $(this).parent().attr("id");

        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
            url: "SessionHandler.ashx",
             data: "headerLink=" + linkHeaderID + "&link=" + this.id
            });                              
        });
```

Problem:

For the first  3 to 5 selection of link is working properly. After that the control is not hitting the SessionHandler.ashx page.

Regards,
Geetha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a caching issue. Try setting the cache property also. See **[jQuery.ajax( settings )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

Try

```
$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           cache: false,
            url: "SessionHandler.ashx",
             data: "headerLink=" + linkHeaderID + "&link=" + this.id
            });                              
        });
```